# Immutable sub vector of immutable vector

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say I have one `const vector<string>` with some elements in it and I'd like to create a `const` subset of that vector, how can I do that?

Ideally it would be cool if C++ supported something like the code below, unfortunately it doesn't. Anybody know of a work around?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile("input.txt"); // contains apple, orange, banana in separate lines
    istream_iterator<string> eos;
    istream_iterator<string> input(infile);
    const vector<string> stuff(input, eos);
    const vector<string> a_stuff(stuff.copy_if([](const string& s) { return s[0] == 'a'; }));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might it be considerable to use the subvector to store indices into the original vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make a copy that contains the subset, you can use a function and assign the result to a `const vector<T>`

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, typename Pred>
std::vector<T> vector_copy_if(std::vector<T> const & vec, Pred && pred)
{
  std::vector<T> result;
  std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(result), pred);
  return result;
}



int main()
{
  std::vector<int> const some_numbers { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  std::vector<int> const even_numbers = vector_copy_if(some_numbers, [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
}
```

Comment: It has a hackish quality to it but that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use a `boost::filter_iterator` to achieve the same result:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const vector<string> v {"apple", "banana", "orange"};
    auto filter= [] (string s){return s.length() > 0 && s[0] == 'a';};
    auto start = boost::make_filter_iterator(filter, v.begin(), v.end());
    auto end   = boost::make_filter_iterator(filter, v.end(), v.end());
    const vector<string> cv (start, end);
}
```